# Passing by reference not working in Visual Basic 2019

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB2019 for this and want to pass an object from one form to another.

In form1, I can call the scan object and access all the methods within that class. When I pass that object to form2, I can no longer access the public methods within that class. I am passing by reference.

This results in the error:

> Public Member `Get_P` on type `Scan` not found

```vb
Class Form1
  ScanObj as Object

  Private Sub BtnDoLogin_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDoLogin.Click
    ...

    Dim oForm2 As Form2
    oForm2 = New Form2()
    oForm2.ScanObject(ScanObj)
    oForm2.Show()
  End Sub
End Class

Class Form2
  Public Sub SetScanObject(ByRef ScanObject)
    'This errors with: Public Member Get_P on type Scan not found
    MsgBox(ScanObject.Get_P())
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is indeed no method called `Get_P` on the type `Object`.  Did you mean to use a different type?  *"In form1, I can call the scan object and access all the methods within that class"* - The code shown does not demonstrate that.  Perhaps your actual code is different?

Comment: David, thanks for looking. Get_P is a public method in my Scan classs

Comment: Where is your `Scan` class used in the code?  Your variables are of type `Object`.  Could you perhaps produce a complete runnable example which demonstrates the problem?  (Either with an online VB fiddle, or even something that can be pasted into Visual Studio.)

Comment: @David VB with `Option Strict Off` allows passing around various types as `Object`s and use late binding on them.

Comment: In form2, where are you calling SetScanObject?  In your Form1 buttonclick you're calling oForm2.ScanObject(ScanObject).  Is that a typo in your example maybe?

Comment: Just write proper code. Turn `Option Strict On`, declare the type of every variable and parameter and stop using `ByRef` when it's not required. This question has absolutely nothing at all to do with passing by reference. You should not be using `ByRef` there in the first place and you would still be getting that same error message. If the message says that type `Scan` has no public member named `Get_P` then it's because that type has no such member. You need to provide a [proper example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can test to show you why.

Comment: `ByRef` with object types is confusing.  You might think that you need to do that to not get a copy of the object (as in C++), but that's not correct.  Because of the reference semantics for objects in .NET, all objects are already passed by reference.  You use `ByRef` when you might want to change the reference to point to a different object (vs. the "normal" case where you want to modify the properties or call the methods on the object that was passed to you).